# UnimplementedException when running Curator examples

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

**Environment**: Windows 10, OpenJDK 12, Zookeeper 3.5.5, Curator 4.2.0

When i try to run Curator asynch examples from here: https://github.com/apache/curator/tree/master/curator-examples/src/main/java/pubsub, i get following exceptions for every event:

```
2019-08-13 13:26:59 INFO  PrepRequestProcessor:878 - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10005d7e4740000 type:createTtl cxid:0xa5 zxid:0x1c txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:null Error:KeeperErrorCode = Unimplemented
2019-08-13 13:26:59 ERROR Publisher:128 - Could not publish message: LocationAvailable{name='us', availableUntil=PT1S} Message{id='1', priority=high}
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$UnimplementedException: KeeperErrorCode = Unimplemented for /root/pubsub/messages/locations/admin/high/1
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:106)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:54)
    at org.apache.curator.x.async.details.BackgroundProcs.lambda$makeProc$2(BackgroundProcs.java:61)
    at org.apache.curator.x.async.details.InternalCallback.processResult(InternalCallback.java:53)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.sendToBackgroundCallback(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:883)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.processBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:653)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.sendBackgroundResponse(CreateBuilderImpl.java:859)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.access$1400(CreateBuilderImpl.java:51)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$6.processResult(CreateBuilderImpl.java:660)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateZK35$1.processResult(CreateZK35.java:38)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.processEvent(ClientCnxn.java:654)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:510)
```

Using an external Zk instance, or updating the example Zk dependencies from 3.5.4-beta to 3.5.5 doesn't help.

Downgrading Curator e.g. to 4.1.0 doesn't even run on OpenJDK 12 with various class-loading and compile metadada exceptions.

"Usual" non-asynch Curator use-cases like creating and accessing Zk nodes, retrieving data and such work without issues.

This surely isn't the case with Curator/Zk versions mismatch as described in other questions here, because obviously i just check out the code from github and run it, so i bet there's something to do maybe with newer Java compatibility, or they never updated the examples for the latest Curator version, or something else.

Can't create an issue on Curator github either, so posting here, appreciate any insight, especially from Curator guys.

Comment: FYI - Curator has been at Apache since 2013. You create issues for it here: http://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CURATOR

Comment: you wrote "Can't create an issue on Curator github either". You create issues on our Apache Jira not Github.